# How to insert doc comments using syn?

Tags: rust, comments, documentation, syn

I have this little snippet that is trying to append comments to a source file.

```rs
    let mut file: File = syn::parse_str(file_content.as_str()).expect("Failed to parse Rust code");

    for item in &mut file.items {
        // Use quote! to generate a comment and append it to the item
        let mut comment: Attribute = parse_quote! {
            /// This is a generated comment.
        };

        comment.style = AttrStyle::Outer;

        match item {
            Item::Struct(ref mut s) => {
                s.attrs.push(comment.clone());
            }
            Item::Enum(ref mut e) => {
                e.attrs.push(comment.clone());
            }
            Item::Fn(ref mut f) => {
                f.attrs.push(comment.clone());
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }
```

But this is the result:

```
#[doc = r" This is a generated comment."]
pub struct MTContainerGuardMut<'a, T> {
    data: *mut T,
    #[cfg(debug_assertions)]
    flag: &'a AtomicBool,
    #[cfg(not(debug_assertions))]
    _phantom: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}
```

I was expecting a comment of the form `/// this is a comment`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`///` and `//!` are, in a sense, **not really comments:** they are syntax sugar for the `#[doc]` attribute. Actual comments are discarded at parse time and cannot be manipulated by `syn`.

So, your generated code is valid, and will produce documentation text. It is just spelled a little differently.